# Cannot connect to SQL server database from Wildfly

Tags: sql-server, database, jboss, wildfly, datasource

I am trying to make a connection between Wildfly 18 and SQL Server 2017. I have added the driver `mssql-jdbc-7.2.2.jre11.jar` to the path `C:\wildfly-18.0.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base\com\microsoft\sqlserver\main`. In the same folder I have added a `module.xml` file with the following content:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="com.microsoft.sqlserver">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="mssql-jdbc-7.2.2.jre11.jar" />
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

In `C:\wildfly-18.0.0.Final\standalone\configuration\standalone.xml` file I have the next:

```
<datasources>
    <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" statistics-enabled="${wildfly.datasources.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}">
        <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
        <driver>h2</driver>
        <security>
            <user-name>sa</user-name>
            <password>sa</password>
        </security>
    </datasource>
    <datasource jndi-name="java:/MSSQLDS" pool-name="MSSQLDS">
        <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;DatabaseName=xpresscr</connection-url>
        <driver-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver-class>
        <driver>sqlserver</driver>
        <security>
            <user-name>xpression</user-name>
            <password>xpression</password>
        </security>
        <validation>
            <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mssql.MSSQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
            <background-validation>true</background-validation>
        </validation>
    </datasource>
    <drivers>
        <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
            <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
        </driver>
        <driver name="sqlserver" module="com.microsoft.sqlserver">
            <driver-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver-class>
        </driver>
    </drivers>
</datasources>
```

I added the datasource from the HAL console. However when testing the connection in the HAL console I get this error:

```
"WFLYJCA0040: failed to invoke operation: WFLYJCA0047: Connection is not valid"
```

[image]

Finally, in the `server.log` file I get this exception:

```
2021-07-28 12:39:45,033 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 18.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 10.0.0.Final) started in 1110ms - Started 316 of 578 services (369 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
2021-07-28 12:40:23,114 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:/MSSQLDS]
2021-07-28 12:40:23,255 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (External Management Request Threads -- 2) IJ000604: Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.17.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:345)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.17.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:352)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.17.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:287)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.17.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:1328)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.17.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:499)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.17.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.internalTestConnection(AbstractPool.java:1067)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.17.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool.testConnection(OnePool.java:93)
    at org.jboss.as.connector@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.common.pool.PoolOperations$TestConnectionInPool.invokeCommandOn(PoolOperations.java:240)
    at org.jboss.as.connector@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.common.pool.PoolOperations$1.execute(PoolOperations.java:97)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@10.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:999)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@10.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:743)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@10.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:467)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@10.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1413)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@10.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.internalExecute(ModelControllerImpl.java:423)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@10.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.lambda$execute$1(ModelControllerImpl.java:243)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-private@1.10.3.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAs(SecurityIdentity.java:289)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-private@1.10.3.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAs(SecurityIdentity.java:255)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@10.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:243)
    at org.jboss.as.domain-http-interface@10.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.DomainApiHandler.handleRequest(DomainApiHandler.java:212)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.encoding.EncodingHandler.handleRequest(EncodingHandler.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.domain-http-interface@10.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.DomainApiCheckHandler.handleRequest(DomainApiCheckHandler.java:93)
    at org.jboss.as.domain-http-interface@10.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.ElytronIdentityHandler.lambda$handleRequest$0(ElytronIdentityHandler.java:62)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-private@1.10.3.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAs(SecurityIdentity.java:313)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-private@1.10.3.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAs(SecurityIdentity.java:270)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@10.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AccessAuditContext.doAs(AccessAuditContext.java:254)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@10.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AccessAuditContext.doAs(AccessAuditContext.java:225)
    at org.jboss.as.domain-http-interface@10.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.ElytronIdentityHandler.handleRequest(ElytronIdentityHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.BlockingHandler.handleRequest(BlockingHandler.java:56)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:376)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot open database "xpresscr" requested by the login. The login failed. ClientConnectionId:53217f16-f5a2-46d9-b596-13a9d01b1691
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver//com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:262)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver//com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:258)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver//com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:104)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver//com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:5036)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver//com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:3668)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver//com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:3627)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver//com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7194)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver//com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2935)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver//com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2456)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver//com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2103)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver//com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1950)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver//com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1162)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver//com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:735)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.17.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:321)
    ... 35 more

2021-07-28 12:40:23,271 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (External Management Request Threads -- 2) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("test-connection-in-pool") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "MSSQLDS")
]) - failure description: "WFLYJCA0040: failed to invoke operation: WFLYJCA0047: Connection is not valid"
```

From MS SQL Server Management Studio I can connect to `xpresscr` database with `xpression` user. I  don't know why I can't connect from Wildfly. Any help?

Thank you!!

Comment: _Cannot open database "xpresscr" requested by the login. The login failed._ Do you have multiple editions/instances of SQL Server installed on your machine? `127.0.0.1:1433` will be attempting to connect to the "default" instance, usually called `MSSQLSERVER`.

Comment: Hi @AlwaysLearning, thank you for replying. This is a new Windows machine. I just installed SQL Server 2017. I only created one database, added one user and changed some settings.

Comment: In SQL Server [2017] Configuration Manager > SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols for MSSQLSERVER have you enabled the TCP/IP protocol? Is it configured to listen on 127.0.0.1 port 1433? Note: if you change settings in here you need to restart the SQL Server service for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Hi @AlwaysLearning, TCP/IP protocol is enabled. In its properties, in the "IP Address" tab I have four "IP + number" and one "IPAll". The "IP4" has the IP address 127.0.0.1. The rest of the "IP + number" have different IP addresses. All of these "IP + number" settings are active but not enabled.

Comment: Hadn't noticed this before, _SQLServerException: Cannot open database "xpresscr" requested by the login. The login failed_. That suggests that it's able to establish a TCP connection, but that there is some security configuration/user mapping that hasn't happened yet. Try having a look in the SQL Server ERRORLOG file for login failure events, 18456, and then compare the State number against [MSSQLSERVER_18456](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error) to see what SQL Server thinks the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

1. Ensure that your SQL SERVER is listening 1433 port:
   [image: Check SQL Server listening port]

2. If so probably your connection string is invalid, please try
connection string in following format:
`sqlserver://{username}:{password}@{host}:{port}?database={dbname}`
i.e. `sqlserver://sa:123@127.0.0.1:1433?database=xpresscr`